# How to replace SwipeRefreshLayout loading animation with a Lottie animation

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout, lottie

I'm trying to replace SwipeRefreshLayout loading animation with a Lottie animation

I have gone through all the libraries listed in [android arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/78), none of them is feasible for my requirement as they do not implement Lottie animation and all the libraries have pre-coded animation

I have also tried this library which says ["LottieSwipeRefreshLayout"](https://github.com/timrijckaert/LottieSwipeRefreshLayout) from Github. but it is not working, as the animation is not visible, I do not want to use a library for such a small concept please suggest me the best way to implement.

Help me like this very much important for my task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["LottieSwipeRefreshLayout"](https://github.com/timrijckaert/LottieSwipeRefreshLayout) worked out for me. the main catch is to use attribute app:layout_type="content" in your recyclerview,scroll view, nested scroll view etc.

Also to customize the Lottie animation modification can be done in  listeners  onTriggerListener and onProgressListener which are overridden in  LottiePullToRefreshLayout class